# Confidence interval of prediction from glm model

Tags: r, prediction, glm, confidence-interval

I am trying to obtain the 95% confidence interval of the prediction from a `glm`. Below is my model

```
library(caret)
library(ISLR)
data(Smarket)
glm.fit <- glm(Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2, data = Smarket, family = binomial)
```

Now I tried with below code to estimate the 95% confidence interval for prediction

```
> head(predict(glm.fit, interval="confidence", level = 0.025))
          1           2           3           4           5           6 
 0.05554775 -0.01128128 -0.04222017  0.07288089  0.05806364  0.03169772 
> head(predict(glm.fit, interval="confidence", level = 0.975))
          1           2           3           4           5           6 
 0.05554775 -0.01128128 -0.04222017  0.07288089  0.05806364  0.03169772
```

Clearly this is not giving me right interval as in the both cases, the values are same.

Could you please help me to get the right interval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`predict.glm()` doesn't take the same arguments as `predict.lm` (see `?predict.glm`): you have to do this by hand (or find a package with helper functions).  The following code constructs the lower and upper 95% Wald confidence limits on the logit (log-odds) scale and then uses `plogis()` to back-transform to the probability scale ...

```r
pp <- predict(glm.fit, se.fit = TRUE)
ci_lwr <- with(pp, plogis(fit + qnorm(0.025)*se.fit))
ci_upr <- with(pp, plogis(fit + qnorm(0.975)*se.fit))
```

```r
> head(ci_lwr)
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
0.4842931 0.4596593 0.4451171 0.4780052 0.4796479 0.4759596 
> head(ci_upr)
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
0.5433766 0.5347319 0.5339426 0.5581846 0.5492351 0.5398233
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood the calculation correctly. Shouldn't it be calculated as `X = c(1, as.vector(as.matrix(Smarket[1, c('Lag1', 'Lag2')]))); qnorm(0.025, X %*% coef(glm.fit), sqrt(X %*% vcov(glm.fit) %*% as.matrix(X, nrow = 3))); ## -0.0628`?

Comment: if you specify `se.fit`, R computes the `sqrt(X %*% vcov() %*% t(X))` stuff for you automatically.  The number you got is the correct answer for the log-odds scale (i.e. the same as `with(pp, fit[1] + qnorm(0.025)*se.fit[1])`) but I assumed you wanted the confidence intervals on the data (i.e. probability) rather than the link (i.e. logit) scale so I used `plogis()` to back-transform ...